# Onmouseover adding HTML inside showtext('foo')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking to add a line break and link inside the `;showtext('MAP');` that displays onmouseover.

```
    <area onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();showtext(' ')"onmouseover="MM_swapImage('lmap','','images/map_z4.png',1);showtext('MAP');" title="MAP" alt="MAP" href="/plan.php?zone=0" coords="630" shape="poly">
```

I've tried single quotes and double quotes with no avail. Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Wow, it's like 1999 all over again!  You can probably get the line break by using \n, but given that it is showtext, and not showhtml, it probably won't take a link (that is actually clickable).    In all seriousness, this coding style is 10+ years obsolete and I would highly suggest re-thinking what you are building with a more modern approach.

Comment: I'm currently updating legacy code on a site nearly 10 years old. The suggested \n did not get the desired line break.